# How to create window with 32bit depth in ubuntu using wxWidgets?

Tags: wxwidgets

Hi I am creating a window using wxWidgets, and in Ubuntu by default windows have a 24 bit depth. But I want a 32 bit depth window.

What can I do to create a window with a 32 bit depth ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the window depth? In wxWidgets API only bitmaps have depth, windows don't.

Comment: In ubuntu each window has colordepth know, using xwininfo command i checked the depth. Now i found how to create 32 bit depth window. While iam using SetBackgroundStyle() window has 32 bit depth, if not 24bit depth window was created. Now the problem is SetBackgroundStyle() didn't transparent my window it looks white background.

Comment: Sorry, still no idea what the problem is. If `SetBackgroundStyle()` doesn't work for you, ask a question about this, with all the relevant details.

Comment: Ok my scenario is create one transparent window with title bar and draw shapes over the transparent window using EVT_PAINT.For achieving this i tried to create transparent window using SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_TRANSPARENT). But i cannot get transparent window.My platform is Ubuntu.

Comment: Finally i got with the help of cairo.  GtkWidget* widget = GetHandle();  cairo_t *cr = gdk_cairo_create(widget->window);
cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
cairo_set_operator (cr, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
cairo_paint (cr);